# Mostrar PDF con urlPath Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, pdf, xcode

Actualmente tengo un webservice el cual me devuelve un array de bytes el cual trasformo en base64 para armar el PDF, este se guarda en una ruta y si voy a la ruta puedo abrir el pdf normalmente.

Todo esto lo hago en

```
func saveBase64StringToPDF(base64String: String, fileName: String) {

    guard
        var documentsURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last,
        let convertedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String)
        else {
            //handle error when getting documents URL
            self.showMessageAlert(strTitle: NSLocalizedString("strErrorTitle",comment:""), strMessage: NSLocalizedString("strErrorPdfMsg",comment:""))
            return
    }

    //name your file however you prefer
    documentsURL.appendPathComponent(fileName)

    do {
        try convertedData.write(to: documentsURL)
    } catch {
        //handle write error here
        self.showMessageAlert(strTitle: NSLocalizedString("strErrorTitle",comment:""), strMessage: NSLocalizedString("strErrorPdfMsg",comment:""))
    }
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    print(documentsURL)


}
```

y en `documentsURL` me queda la ruta del archivo pdf  lo que no puedo es mostrar o abrir este archivo.

Probé con `UIApplication.shared.open(documentsURL)` y con `webView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi de la siguiente forma

```
 var docController:UIDocumentInteractionController!
  self.docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: documentsURL)
                        docController.presentOptionsMenu(from: self.view.frame, in: self.view, animated: true)
```